# Is it possible to include ggplot command or data argument as a footnote to the plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

...of course it can be done manually using annotation and the typing the whole command again, but I would prefer something like:

qplot(...)+annotation_command()

(because the manual option means that I have to change the code at two places)

This would be especially useful when creating lots of plots in a data exploration and one wants to keep it reproducible.
If it is not possible it would be the next best, to include the argument of "data", because it is a common hassle that it cannot be reproduced which subset is shown in a certain plot.

Thanks in advance!
Elisabeth

Comment: Look at package `knitr` to include graphics alongside the code chunks/comments used to create them (and lots moer besides).

Comment: Thanks! Not exactly what I was looking for, but the package looks very promising - I will give it a try in the next weeks. Especially in connection with LyX and Rstudio it might be of some help.